# What client is connecting to Azure SQL Data Warehouse?

Tags: azure-synapse

I am planning to automate the KILL of user queries running over a configurable amount of time.  I see that

```
sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions
```

has the login_name, but the client_id column looks to me like an Azure IP (104.*) and not the IP (10.*) from my company's servers/PCs.

Is it possible to know the client context for an ADW query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you connect from your laptop to Azure SQL DW the IP will usually match your public IP. Compare to http://www.myipaddress.com and see if it matches. It won't be your internal 10.* IP address because you can't put Azure SQL DW on a VNET at the moment.

Answer (score 1):

`sys.dm_pdw_exec_sessions` also has app_name, which gives some good details, for example:

[image: app_name]

'Mashup Engine' in the above example is Power BI Desktop.

You could also instigate a policy that all queries had to use the `LABEL` syntax to give additional query context, kill queries that don't comply?  See below for additional details:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-data-warehouse/sql-data-warehouse-develop-label